# Map a function that uses the lists indices as arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, map, index

Suppose I have a function `f[x_]` that I want to `Map` over some`list` (assumed to be one dimensional for the sake of simplicity) - this can be readily done. Now suppose the function depends not only a single variable (the list element), but also on where the element is located on the list; for example `f[x_,i_+1,i_-1]`, where `i` is supposed to be the location of `x` in `list`. This is easy when we use `Do` loops to carry out such tasks, but as it is known to be less efficient than using inbuilt functions, how can I keep track of the location where `Map` is currently applying `f` and then pass it to `f` as arguments.

Comment: `but also on where the element is located on the list` lookup `MapIndexed`  btw, it is always easier to understand something with a MWE.

Comment: `MapIndexed`  should do what I want. What's an MWE?

Comment: It should be `MapIndexed[f[#, #2[[1]] + 1, #2[[1]] - 1]&, list]`

Comment: @duality MWE: "minimal working example"

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

```
f[{a_, b_}] := 2 a + b

v = {2, 5, 8};

f /@ MapIndexed[{#1, #2[[1]]} &, v]
```

{5, 12, 19}

**2.**

```
g[a_, {b_}] := 2 a + b

g @@@ MapIndexed[List, v]
```

{5, 12, 19}

Answer (score 1):

```
f[{a_, b_}] := 2  a + b

v = {2, 5, 8};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's example and using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[f[{#1, #2}] &, {#, Range[Length[#]]}] &@v

(*{5, 12, 19}*)
```